# omnet++ : how to rebuild added source codes to existing class?

Tags: omnet++

I am using Omnet 4.2.2. For my project, I want to write a function `calculateKShortestPaths(src, dest)` to calculate k-shorstest paths from src to dest nodes. I come up with two options to make it available for use. One option is to add directly into existing `cTopology` class. The other option is to subclass the cTopology class in my own project class. I prefer option 1 (to add directly to `cTopology` class) since it has just a little change, and I can use `cTopology` seamlessly, but how can I rebuild it? And any idea for option 2 please? Thanks a lot.

Danh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rebuild `cTopology` just open terminal, go to the main directory of `OMNeT++` and type `make`.